# Placing controls above the layer in the preview using the plugin cordova-plugin-camera-preview

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to use this photo camera plugin [cordova-plugin-camera-preview](https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview-sample-app) in an HTML hybrid application and it works, but I can not place the controls on the camera layer while I focus. However, they appear above the layer when I take the photo and the camera shows the preview. Does anyone know if there is any configuration that can make the buttons appear on the camera layer?

[image: capture]

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution in this line in js/index.js

```
  var app = {
    startCameraAbove: function(){
    CameraPreview.show();  
    CameraPreview.startCamera({x: 0, y: 0, width: window.screen.width, height: 
  window.screen.height, camera: "back", toBack: true, previewDrag: false, tapPhoto: true});
  },
```

At the beginning of the js/index.js script we must place these values ​​in **toBack:true** to keep the camera back completely (be careful, the HTML background can cover it, I recommend put background: transparent in CSS), it is also recommended change ***previewDrag: false*** to avoid unveiling the background.